# Prototype function polluting JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, apply

I'm working with an API that can accept multiple arrays in which I'm using `apply()` to pass the arrays, but the array contains a prototype function that I cannot seem to remove from the individual array.  What ends up happening is that prototype function being executed.

This is the prototype function:
    `if ( !Array.prototype.last ) { Array.prototype.last = function(){ return this[this.length - 1]; }}`

For example when I log each array I see the following in my eventList array:

```
["name1", "index1", "value1", last: function]
["name2", "index2", "value2", last: function]
["name3", "index3", "value3", last: function]
```

I then push the arrays:

```
apiName.push.apply( apiName, eventList );
```

I've tried `array.pop()` to remove the 'last' function on each array, but to no avail.

How does the prototype function end up in the array in the first place and how would I prevent it from being called in the apply()?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are Objects in JavaScript. They can have properties and prototypes just like an Object.

Ex:

```
var a = [];
a.foo = "bar";
```

This is completely valid. But is `"bar"` *in the Array*?

Let's ask:

```
console.log(a.length); // 0
console.log(a.foo); // "bar"
```

So: **no**, it's not *in the Array* but it does exist as a property of the Object.

Just like with properties adding things to the prototype doesn't affect the value of `.length`.

It's a bit unfortunate (confusing) that you see the custom prototype when logging, but I would attribute that to a customization in your debugger.

Comment: Would using apply() still run that prototype function?

Comment: No, `apply()` only runs the function you're applying. Maybe it would be easier if you used `concat()` instead? `apiName = apiName.concat(eventList);`